# If statement true for element attribute check, but breaks anyways

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, getattribute

So I am working on a selenium surf automation of [this website](https://www.facebook.com/ads/library/?active_status=active&ad_type=all&country=ALL&q=%22%20%22&sort_data%5Bdirection%5D=desc&sort_data%5Bmode%5D=relevancy_monthly_grouped&start_date%5Bmin%5D=2023-02-20&start_date%5Bmax%5D=&search_type=keyword_exact_phrase&media_type=all&content_languages%5B0%5D=en) ->

[*See attached image to understand the issue better*](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IItlL.png)

The problem im facing is, the code (see below) allows for two exact same (seemingly) ads to be true for the main if statement, which checks for the current element selected, having the proper attributes to comply with my codes purpose.

However the first ad on this page, becomes true for the main statement as it should, but then breaks after hitting the line right after it `button_text = starting_element`. But the ad right after it, its able to traverse past that line and onto the rest of the nested loop etc.

This issue arises randomly (seemingly) amongst different ads throughout the page (of course the ones without any -call to action- button, being skipped, makes sense), but with no clear reason as to why.

```
while(True):
            starting_element.send_keys(Keys.TAB)
            WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//body/div/div/div[@role='main']/div/div/div/div/div/div/div[4]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]")))
            starting_element = browser.switch_to.active_element
            # check for a set of keywords when a CTA button is targeted, if matched then extract URL from source
            if starting_element.get_attribute('role') == "button" and starting_element.get_attribute('aria-busy') == "false" and starting_element.get_attribute('tabindex') == '0':
                button_text = starting_element.text
                if button_text in meta_cta_buttons:
                    parent_element = starting_element.find_element(By.XPATH, "..")
                    while (True):
                        if parent_element.tag_name != 'a':
                            # moves up element ancestry chain 
                            parent_element = parent_element.find_element(By.XPATH, "..") 
                        else:
                            cta_url = parent_element.get_attribute('href')
                            # store links in a set
                            unique_store_urls.add(cta_url)
                            break
                else:
                    continue
            else:
                continue
            try:
                # to look for the loading page data as part of infinite scroll
                spinner_element = WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//span[@role='progressbar']//*[name()='svg']")))
                end_of_page_element = browser.find_element(By.XPATH, "//a[contains(text(),'Ad Library API')]")
                if spinner_element:
                    print("Spinner exists")
                    time.sleep(3)
                # if its at the footer, it means no data was loaded in time
                elif starting_element == end_of_page_element:
                    break
            except TimeoutException:
                print("Spinner doesn't exist")
                continue
```

I have printed out the result of the variables for the ad its breaking on, and that elements values are all correct. So im quite lost.

Comment: Sorry, should I be providing the whole script? From what you shared, it also seems providing more code is not the solution. So what do i do? Stackoverflow just downvotes your question to infinity, but won't tell you the problem...

Comment: The problem is: without a reproducible test case it is incredibly hard (if not impossible) to understand the problem and very few people would even try to help.

Comment: That's understandable, i just felt like adding 100 lines of code is more of a deterrent for help. Will fix this for next question, i figured the problem here out.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed my own problem.

Turns out the issue was with part of the code I didn't provide for more context in this question. It was the actual `set` which was missing the keywords in lowercase to check for.

Thus the if statement was bypassing the ads quite simply.